# Rearrange columns as per column headers - Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I want to rearrange columns as per column headers. I found the below macro on this platform.

I get the error at this line code.

```
If cel.value=correctOrder(col - 1) Then
```

This is the error

> "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

```vb
Sub rearrange_Cols()
Dim correctOrder() As Variant
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim headerRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim mainWS As Worksheet

Set mainWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base")

' Edit this to be the correct order you need
correctOrder() = Array("FT Id", "FT Name", "FT Primary Location", "Deployed Location", " Approval Status", "Approved By", " Approved on Date", "FT acceptance Status", "Skill", " Billed", "Date of Joining"," Year" )
' Now, we know that the number of headers you have to rearrange are `UBound(CorrectOrder)+1`

With mainWS
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set headerRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))
End With

Dim newWS As Worksheet
Set newWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
newWS.Name = "New Open"

Dim col As Long
With newWS
    For col = 1 To lastCol
        For Each cel In headerRng
            If cel.Value = correctOrder(col - 1) Then
                mainWS.Columns(cel.Column).Copy .Columns(col)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    Next col
End With
```

Comment: what is the value of `col` when it errors?

Comment: `col - 1` is not a valid index then.

Comment: Your array only has 4 elements, but `lastCol` could be a lot larger, as it is independent of your array

Comment: I have more than 30 elements in Array. Ex : Column f, column g, etc. Not sure why the error pops up.

Comment: There are only 4 in the code you posted: if you don't post your actual code then no one's time is being spent wisely...

Comment: I have updated the actual code which I am trying to execute. Here in the array list, I have up to 15 elements. Once the code executes then I'll add more elements. Thank you

Comment: Issue has been resolved. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when your **Base** worksheet has more than **12** columns.

For example if the worksheet has 13 columns.
The **lastCol** variable is set to 13.
It is passed into the **col** variable and when it reaches 13 and is used in `correctOrder(col - 1)` a *Subscript out of range* error is generated.
The **correctOrder** array has 12 elements (zero based), so when it tries to find the 13th, it is out of range.

The simple fix is to hard code the lastCol value.

```
With mainWS
    lastCol = 12
    Set headerRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))
End With
```